# Publishing message from Lambda function to AWS IoT is not working with aws-sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot

I'm trying to publish a message from a lambda function to my AWS IoT Thing, by using the `aws-sdk` which should use HTTP by default instead of MQTT to publish a message.
Then the Function gets invoked no error message is logged to cloudwatch unfortunately which makes it even harder to debug.
Steps I took:

1. created a Policy for the message
2. created a small React frontend to read messages and test it with IoT test client.
3. wrote lambda and passed the Thing url as env var like this: "https://xxxxxdi.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com"

The Lambda function has also a attached Policy which should grant it to write to AWS IoT.

```json
{
      "arn": null,
      "document": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Action": "iot:Publish",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:eu-central-1:*:*:topic/PairCreated",
            "Effect": "Allow"
          }
        ]
      },
      "id": null,
      "name": "PublishMessage",
      "type": "inline"
    }
```

Here is the code of the lambda function. The credentials for the object of type `IotData` are looking ok

```js
import wrap from '@dazn/lambda-powertools-pattern-basic'
import Log from '@dazn/lambda-powertools-logger'
import { IotData } from 'aws-sdk'

export const handler = wrap(async (event: any = {}, context: any)  => {
  Log.info('event', event)
  const iotData = new IotData({endpoint: process.env.IOT_ENDPOINT, region: 'eu-central-1', logger: new Log})

  const params: IotData.PublishRequest = {
    topic: process.env.IOT_THING_NAME || '',
    payload: JSON.stringify(event),
    qos: 0,
    retain: false
  }
  Log.debug('params', { params })

  iotData.publish(params, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      Log.error("Error publishing to IOT", { err })
      return context.fail(err)
    };
    
    Log.info('res', res)
    return context.succeed();
  });
})
```

The version I'm using: `"aws-sdk": "^2.1053.0"`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I found out why the message was not sent.
The callback inside of `iotData.publish` was not executed correctly because the lambda function was terminated before it could be executed. Here are my changes to the code.

```js
await iotData.publish(params, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      Log.error("Error publishing to IOT", { err })
      return context.fail(err)
    };
    
    return context.succeed(res);
  }).promise()
```

This returns a `Promise` we can `await` so the callback gets executed